# ncmpcpp and mpd: jump to marked song after finishing current song

Tags: shortcut-keys, music, mpd, ncmpcpp

I just started using ncmpcpp for the first time, moving from Clementine. In Clementine you can mark a song for playing next, ie. after current song is finished (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>). Is it any similar functionality in ncmpcpp? If not, is there a way I can add it?

Answer (score 0):

select the song that you want to add, press `a` choose `current playlist` then choose `after current song`

Comment: That would move the song to the position after the current song. Changes the playlist order. That's not what I wanted. What I wanted was some song to be marked to be played next, and the pointer to current song moves from current song to the marked song. Unsure if it makes sense.